# Angular5 *ngIf=“afunctioncall(); let L” results in the function being called 4 times

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-ng-if

I am working with Angular 5 and I want an element to return an object after finding from an array upon the result of a function call and then I use `let L` as a variable object to hold that.

When I do this I've noticed that the function is called multiple times.

[image]

I have created a stack-blitz to show this situation. here that function is called 4 times but in my local application, it is called more than 6 times.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypwswn

I know this is because of change detection cycle. but I could not figure out how to solve this situation logically.

I've seen the following post however with it being related to Angular 2. I'm not sure it's relevant

[Angular2 *ngIf="afunctioncall()" results in the function being called 9 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850484/angular2-ngif-afunctioncall-results-in-the-function-being-called-9-times#)

The 'console.log is output 4 times.

Can anyone point me or am I missing anything?

And is there any way to avoid it?

Any help will be appreciated.

I need to pass a array to that method and get a selected leg from that array.

[image: This is View]
[image: This is method]

Comment: The Angular 2 solution is still relevant.

Comment: Can you please explain that solution? @YounesM

Comment: @UmerMehAr what don't you understand about that solution? Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: i am passing a custom selected object from a Array based on User Interaction. So how can i call that in Constructor or ngOnInit?

Comment: @UmerMehAr Instead of calling the function in the .html, where there are change detections, just do all the work on the .ts and display the result : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drxdyn

Comment: @YounesM i need to pass leg array from template to that method.

Comment: Why do it from the template? Can you provide some more code?

Comment: i just edit 2 more pics. have a look and share your thoughts in this case. My bad i should have add them earlier. @YounesM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the function in ngOnInit instead on your template

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

finaldata : any;


ngOnInit() {

     this.finaldata = this.getSelectedLeg(this.data);

  }


}
```

in html

```
<div *ngIf="finaldata; let L">

</div>
```

Comment: i appreciated but Can you please see my question again i have added 2 more pics

Comment: what was your problem right now can you explain clearly

Comment: My problem is when i add `console.log(...)` in getSelectedLeg method it console more then 5 6 times. as it should be only 1 time. angular change detector detect changed somewhere else but it also invoke this function perhaps.