# What type of expression should be used in an Angular ngIf directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

Working in an Angular project I realized that when I used a method as the expression to be evaluated in a `*ngIf` directive, the method was called multiple times. Looking into the reason I found that it's normal and expected behavior, it will call on every change detection cycle:

- [using-a-function-in-ngif-runs-several-times-instead-of-once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957386/using-a-function-in-ngif-runs-several-times-instead-of-once)
- [angular2-ngif-afunctioncall-results-in-the-function-being-called-9-times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850484/angular2-ngif-afunctioncall-results-in-the-function-being-called-9-times/41171279)

The question then is: what type of expression should be used in this and others directives? A component variable (undefined|defined|true|false|...), a method returning a boolean, it depends on the implementation?

Does anyone know of any blog or best practices article where this topic is discussed and what they recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: The only best practice here is to avoid a computation heavy expression, anything else is fine. My personal favorite is to use only component variable but that's an opinion.

Comment: On Push Change Detection Strategy may help you to limitate such behavior, you can read more here : https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4