# Angular JS isNumber on ng-switch-when not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular. I am trying to do switch the `div` based on some condition :

```
  <td>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
      <img ng-if="row.pin" ng-src="{{pinImageUrl}}" alt="Pinned @ {{row.pin}}" class="img-pin" />
      <div ng-switch="checkUrl">
        <a ng-switch-when="{{isNumber(row.id)}}" href="numberUrl ">
          {{getName(row)}}
        </a>
        <a ng-switch-when="url" href="{{url + row.id}}">
          {{getName(row)}}
        </a>
        <span ng-switch-default href="aaaaaa">
          {{getName(row)}}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
```

But `{{isNumber(row.id)}}` not working. Can someone tell me what is wrong here ?

Comment: try angular.isNumber.......      https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isNumber

Comment: also instead of href it is nice to use ng-href.......    https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: what is the `checkUrl` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div ng-switch="checkUrl">
    <a ng-switch-when="{{isNumber(row.id)}}" href="numberUrl ">
      {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
    <a ng-switch-when="url" href="{{url + row.id}}">
      {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
    <span ng-switch-default href="aaaaaa">
      {{getName(row)}}
    </span>
  </div>
```

The `expression` in the `ng-switch` can be a scope function call, scope variable or can be a value. But in `ng-switch-when="something"`, here  `something` should be a value. It didn't work even if we mention scope variable or function call. What you mention, it takes it as a value and then compares the value in the `ng-switch` then renders if matches. But in your code, you are calling a function `isNumber()` in `ng-switch-when`. So, it is not matching. Even in the second case, it should be a value of `url`, not variable. But if you want to use functions to render the DOM, go for `ng-if` instead of `ng-switch`. ng-`if="funcA()"` will work, but executes(watches) on every digest cycle to know the value. But calling a function inside `ng-if` is also not a good solution. For more info [ng-if being called more times than it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040151/ng-if-being-called-more-times-than-it-should)

Comment: How will it work when checkUrl == url but the id is number ?