# Scope function calling on DOM change(two-way data binding) angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);

    function SimpleController($scope) {
      $scope.isNumberA = function(val) {
        console.log('called');
        if (val == 2) return true;
      }
    }
  </script>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="switcher" />
  <h1 ng-if="isNumberA(10)">isNumber</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

In the above code first time, `isNumberA` calling because of `ng-if="isNumberA(10)"` but I don't know why it is calling another time. Check console, it prints two times on DOM render in brower. After that when I click on check box again it calling the function. Why this method calling on check box click? I didn't called it. Is this the two-way binding? And also if I remove the `<h1 ng-if="isNumberA(10)"></h1>`, it is not calling. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-if will evaluate its expression when digest cycle runs, basically you shouldn't make an function call from ng-if expression.

**DEMO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);
    function SimpleController($scope) {
      $scope.isNumberA = function(val) {
        console.log('called');
        if (val == 2) $scope.block = true;
        $scope.block = false;
      }
    }
  </script>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="switcher" />
  <span ng-init="isNumberA(10)"></sapn>
   <h1 ng-if="block">isNumber</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

Read More here

[ng-if being called more times than it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040151/ng-if-being-called-more-times-than-it-should)

Comment: Please elaborate your answer

Answer (score 2):

You have used a function call rather then a variable for condition (ng-if).
Angular watch every scope variable used in view, but when you use a function call, it can't decided which variable or event will effect this function return value, so Angular run such function on every digest cycle.
You should call this function in ng-init and store the return value of this function in a variable, and use that variable in ng-if.

```
$scope.isNumberA = function(val) {
    console.log('called');
    if (val == 2){
        $scope.showIfBlock = true;
    } else {
        $scope.showIfBlock = false;
    }
  }


<span ng-init="isNumberA(10)"></sapn>
<h1 ng-if="showIfBlock">isNumber</h1>
```